# Nativescript - vertical align a Label text to the top (iOS)

Tags: nativescript

Is it possible to position the text of a Label element at the top on iOS?

The default seems to vertically centered.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done using -

```
<Label verticalAlignment="top" text="some text"></Label>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me - the text is **always** centered - no matter what I've tried so far (IOS 12.4)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a bit of good old fashioned padding in your CSS? `padding: 0 10 20 10` should align the text in the label at the top.

Comment: I will try this...though this solution seems to be very dependent on the font-size and the label element height.

Comment: Even though this might just work, it may disturb the neighbouring layouts.